# Numeric file identifier like __FILE__ for logging purposes

Tags: c, gcc, eclipse-cdt, ld

I have a couple of rather large gcc-based C-projects (more than 400 files, partially shared by the projects) where each file has something like a file id for logging output. This boils down to something like this:

```
// At start of each c-file
#include "log.h"
#define MOD_ID 12 // "Unique" number for each file
...
TRACE("hello world");
```

With log.h:

```
// log.h
#define TRACE(msg) printf("module=%d msg=%s", MOD_ID, msg) // Fixed format with number and text
```

This concept is flawed in two respects:

- The MOD_IDs are hard to maintain and get easily duplicated
- The messages are sent across network and the receiver does not know, which id belongs to which module, which makes Debugging hard, as each time, the MOD_ID needs to be searched in the correct source code.

I would like to change this so that the uniqueness is guaranteed by compiler/linker and at the same time, I would like to have a "dictionary" or "lookup-table" for each program. I could use `__FILE__` for creating one part of the dictionary, but how do I create a unique number for each file (starting at 0 and no (large) holes allowed - that requirement comes from a different part of the code)? Is there an existing solution or do I have to invent the wheel myself?

Comment: In one translation unit https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: I think this cannot be done by the compiler. Depending on your build system you could use scripts to generate IDs, check for duplicates, create the dictionary. Think about the dictionary. Will it be generated during the build, independently from previous versions? Will it be saved in your source code management system? Do you need to keep the same assignment of IDs to filenames for all versions of the software? What should happen when files are added, removed or renamed?... I think the easiest way would be manual ID definitions and scripts to generate the dictionary and to check for duplicates

Comment: Unless you want to hide file names or file names  may be duplicate I would simply use file names.

Comment: I think you can create a hash function for the file paths and have a separate executable to check the uniqueness of the values after each compilation

Comment: I also have `__FUNCTION__` available (MSVC) and for an id I just pick a random large number from my head, knowing it is very unlikely to be duplicated, in any file/function. That doesn't qualify for your "no holes" though.

Comment: @pifor Agreed. But this is dealing with a very bad preexisting design.  Filenames are a LOT more useful.  Given a `MOD_ID`, to find out where a log entry came from means searching through the entire code base where every file has a `MOD_ID` token.  Use `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` so the log entry ***tells you immediately and exactly where it came from***.  Format the log entries properly and it's easy to parse the files.

Comment: @pifor This is not possible as the tracing client and a lot of devices are already installed, so I need to stay compatible :-(

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround: define enumeration in log.h, and require that each source file uses enumeration constant to define `MOD_ID` instead of plain integer.

**log.h**

```
enum {
    MODID_HELLO = 0, // Can use enum auto increment or define number manually
    MODID_WORLD = 1
};
#define TRACE(msg) printf("module=%d msg=%s", MOD_ID, msg)
```

**hello.c**

```
#include "log.h"
#define MOD_ID MODID_HELLO
...
TRACE("error message");
```

Benefits:

- ID's defined in one file. Easy to find and helps to avoid duplication.
- Source file will fail to compile if trying to use `TRACE` without `MOD_ID` defined.

Comment: I didn't go this way, as we have at least 1000 files for which I would have to do this manually. And I didn't like the additional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer which I wanted to tick as "correct answer" as it lead me the way I wanted to go, but this answer is somehow gone. So I'm adding the complete way I went.

The suggested answer was roughly: Make the MOD_ID a define in the compiler call.

As we are using Eclipse and we have tons of files, this proved to be a little bit tricky as Eclipse generates the makefile each time the project is built. Eclipse collects all sources in a make variable C_SRCS. This I use as an array of compilation units and for the -D MOD_ID=... I just calculate the index into C_SRCS. This has the advantage that the MOD_ID remains the same unless I add or remove sources from the project.

Start by inserting into `makefile` the line

```
-include ../makefile.init
```

This makefile.init receives the following lines:

```
EMPTY :=
SPACE := $(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
XX := ,

# Return the index of the second parameter in the first parameter, which needs to be a list - comparison just checks partial names from the end
IDX = $(words $(subst $(XX),$(SPACE),$(firstword $(subst $(2)$(XX),$(2)$(SPACE),$(XX)$(subst $(SPACE),$(XX),$(1))$(XX)))))

# Return the index of the parameter in the list of C-Sources
SRCIDX = $(call IDX,$(C_SRCS),$<)
```

SRCIDX is now a macro, that will return the index in C_SRCS given a partial or the complete name. So add to the Preprocessor settings for C-Files:

```
-D MOD_ID=$(call SRCIDX)
```

Now I can remove all #define MOD_ID from all sources.
To get a directory of all IDs, I added an additional target `print-csrc`

```
make -s print-csrc <further parameters>
```

And in makefile

```
print-csrc:
    @echo '$(foreach word,$(C_SRCS),{$(call IDX,$(C_SRCS),$(word)),"$(word)"},${\n})' > csrc.cc

.PHONY: print-csrc
```

This generates a file csrc.cc like this

```
{ 1, "FileA.c" }, { 2, "FileB.c" },
```

which I include in a static variable:

```
static const ID_TEXTS id_texts[] =
{
#include "csrc.cc"
};
```

The list can be read out from the device via web interface or any other channel.